# Running anything Gnome-related in root terminal gives error

Tags: debian, gnome, root

Pretty fresh Debian 6.0.3 install, running Gnome 2.30.2.  In a root terminal, whenever I try to open anything Gnome related, I'll get this error:

```
unable to open display ":0.0"
```

Sometimes this is prefixed by:

```
No protocol specified
```

I've added my hostname to `xhost`, and put `xhost +[myhostname]` in root's `bashrc`, but that just fails when I open the root terminal.  Help?

EDIT: The only way I can get this to work is by turning off access control entirely, but I know there must be a better solution.

Comment: Are you logging in to X11 itself as root or as a normal user?

Comment: Well I don't log in to X11 manually, but my Gnome login is a normal user.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: I didn't say "manually"; GNOME login screen is X11 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"`No protocol specified`" usually means you have been denied access to the X11 display. There are a few ways to do what you want:

- Point `$XAUTHORITY` to your Xauthority file. Sometimes it is `~/.Xauthority` in your home directory; with GNOME it is a temporary file deep in `/var`. The following methods will work in both cases:

  - Just copy the environment variable to your root terminal, using `echo $XAUTHORITY` and `export XAUTHORITY=...`.
  - Make `su` make a copy of Xauthority by adding `pam_xauth` to its PAM configuration.
  - Use `sudo -s`, and configure it to have "`XAUTHORITY`" in its `env_keep` option.
  - Use `gksu gnome-terminal` to launch a root terminal.
- Add `root` to the permitted users, by running `xhost +si:localuser:root` from a normal terminal. This will make Xauthority unnecessary.

Do *not* add the computer's hostname to `xhost`, as this is not reliable (rDNS issues), will not work with local connections (only TCP), and is insecure (allows *any user* to connect to your display).

Comment: Great answer!  Thanks for your help!  Seems sort of odd that Debian would add an application launcher for a root terminal to the panel by default, but not give the root user privileges for the display.  But I guess this is a security feature, and I just abuse the root terminal.  Thanks again!

Comment: It's not really a feature, only lack thereof. (root already can add himself to Xauthority, for example.) Whoever added the launcher probably assumed that administrators are only going to use terminal-based programs (which most sysadmins are).